# C# Vibration Sensor using External Accelerometer

Tags: c#, winforms, c#-3.0, sensors, vibration

Its been almost 4 years since I've programmed in c# so I'm really rusty. I was given a project to create a program that will be able to read the vibration from an external Vibration Sensor connected via 2x micro usb cable. I am able to obtain the vibration x,y values from the external device however; I now need to plot the raw data obtained in a graph showing amplitude vs time [Example Picture given!](https://stackoverflow.com/image.jpg)[show raw data amplitude vs time](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3mcUC.png). I also need to be able to grab these plotted points in the graph and export them to excel or any other means of storage for later analysis. Can you guys please help or point me in the right direction. Thanks [Vibration results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CtUoj.jpg)

Code example `

```
using Hardware.PR49;

using System;

using System.Collections.Generic;

using System.Threading;

namespace PR49SensorExample

{
    class Program

{
    static void Main(string[] args)

    {
        var task = PR49Detection.GetSerialPortSensorInfos();


        if (!task.Wait(5000))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Searching PR49 timed out.");
            return;
        }

        var all49 = task.Result;

        if (all49.Count == 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("No PR49 connected.");
            return;
        }

        var port = all49[0].Port;
        var sensor = new SerialDevice49(port);
        var sources = sensor.SignalSources;
        var xAxisSource = sources[0];
        var yAxisSource = sources[1];
        var xData = new List<double>();
        var yData = new List<double>();

        try
        {
            sensor.Connect();
            sensor.StartDAQ();
        }
        catch
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Failed to connect or start sensor.");
            return;
        }

        while (xData.Count < 20000)
        {
            xData.AddRange(xAxisSource.ReadDecodedData());
            yData.AddRange(yAxisSource.ReadDecodedData());

            Console.WriteLine($"data points: X: {xData.Count}, Y: {yData.Count}");
            Thread.Sleep(200);
        }

        try
        {
            sensor.StopDAQ();
            sensor.Disconnect();
        }
        catch
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Failed to stop or disconnect sensor.");
            return;
        }

        Console.WriteLine("\nSensor stopped.");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
}
```

`

Comment: does the chart need to keep updating in real time?

Comment: Yes it does @vbp13

Comment: very cool project.  i'm jealous.  My approach would be c#, signalR, charts.js